# Create macro to search Worksheet for list of strings and highlight the row

Tags: excel, excel-2010, string-search, vba

Can someone help me create a macro that will search an Excel worksheet for a list of 30 strings (e.g., `SV-32488r1`, `SV-33485r1`) and highlight the `Row` when found?

- I am using Office 2010.
- I am not a Excel or VBA wiz so I have no idea where to start.
- The searches I have found only allow me to search for one string.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Are you looking to highlight any row in which one of your list of strings is found, or all rows in which one of those strings is found? In addition by 'highlight' do you wish to navigate to that row or do you wish to change the background color of it?

Comment: I would like to highlight every row in which one of the strings are found.  And by highlight, I mean change the background color of the row so I can easily identify the rows.  Thank you so much.

Comment: You can use conditional formatting and `COUNTIF` for this. No VBA required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Sub HighlightListedValues()
    Dim strConcatList As String
    Dim cell As Range

    'Creates a string concatenating your list of strings, separated by |s
    'e.g. "item1|item2|item3|item4|"
    For Each cell In Sheets("List").Range("A1:A30")
        strConcatList = strConcatList & cell.Value & "|"
    Next cell

    'For each used cell in Column A of sheet1, check whether the value in that cell
    'is contained within the concatenated string
    For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange)
        If InStr(strConcatList, cell.Value) > 0 Then       'InStr returns 0 if the string isn't found
            cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Highlights the row in red if value found
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

This will highlight the relevant rows in red if the following is true:

- The data matching the values you are searching for are is in column A of a worksheet named "Sheet1"
- Your list of strings is contained in cells A1:A30 of a worksheet named "List"

Amend the names of worksheets and ranges as needed e.g. If you want to search in Columns A to C of a worksheet named "Data" you would amend `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")` to `Sheets("Data").Range("A:C")`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have changed the lines to:
(Sheets("Gap Analysis").Range("E:E"), Sheets("Gap Analysis").UsedRange)
.
.
.
For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("Gap Analysis").Range("E:E"), Sheets("Gap Analysis").UsedRange)

I am receiving the error "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range"

Comment: Try using the sheet notation and not the sheet name.

Comment: Please elaborate.  I thought "Sheet1" in in Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A") referred to the name of the worksheet I am working in, which is named "Gap Analysis".

Comment: Your assumption is correct, I can only assume there is a typo somewhere e.g. your sheet _appears_ to be named "Gap Analysis" but it might have a space at the end (making it "Gap Analysis ") perhaps? Alternatively you could use the sheet index or sheet codename, explained in more detail [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm)

Comment: I renamed the sheet "Sheet1" and still got the error.  I also attempted to use the sheet codename but it does not like that with .Range appended to it.  Are you sure there isn't something else wrong with this line: For Each cell In Sheets("SV-32248r1|SV-32336r1").Range("E1:E100")

Comment: Public Sub HighlightListedValues()
    Dim strConcatList As String
    Dim cell As Range

       For Each cell In Sheets("SV-32248r1|SV-32336r1").Range("E1:E100")
        strConcatList = strConcatList & cell.Value & "|"
    Next cell
    For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("Gap Analysis").Range("E:E"), Sheets("Gap Analysis").UsedRange)
        If InStr(strConcatList, cell.Value) > 0 Then             cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

Comment: I tested this on my own machine using some test data and it worked fine, could you edit your current macro into your question as it's almost impossible to read just pasted into a comment?

Comment: I attempted to post it cleanly in another answer post but I can't seem to get it to present the code correctly.

Comment: For some reason this only works if I copy the string from the original sheet, it doesn't work if I type it in or paste it in from somewhere else. And it will only take the exact case of the string. Anyway to change it to look for a part of the string?

Comment: @MPineda If you have a new question please ask it by using the Ask Question button.

Answer (score 1):

I have created macro to find the list of words and highlight the cell.
when i use the code it is also highlighting empty cells inbetween the values. also i required the code to find incase the cell contain the word inbetween the words.

Example:
I created to find and highlight the word "Shev" in the cells. it should find and highlight if it is in middle of cell like " was shev in ".

Regards,

Parthi

Code below:

```
Public Sub HighlightListedValues()

Dim strConcatList As String
Dim cell As Range


For Each cell In Sheets("Bad Words").Range("A1:A30")
    strConcatList = strConcatList & cell.Value & "|"
Next cell

    For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("Data").Range("A:Z"), Sheets("data").UsedRange)
    If InStr(strConcatList, cell.Value) > 0 Then
        cell.Interior.Color = 63125789
    End If
Next cell
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Untested the part that colors it in but this should give you a good start

```
'====================================================================================
iWarnColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
' This Group is what I use to delte a row.
' If you want to delete another row just change the term your searching for
    Do
       Set c = SrchRng.find("CHANGE THIS TO WHAT YOU WANT TO FIND", LookIn:=xlValues)
       If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.ColorIndex = iWarnColor
   Loop While Not c Is Nothing
'=====================================================================================
```

Here is what I used in the past to delete rows that contain specific texts

```
Do
       Set c = AsrchRng.find("Date", LookIn:=xlValues)
       If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
   Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    Do
       Set c = AsrchRng.find("Note", LookIn:=xlValues)
       If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
   Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    Do
       Set c = AsrchRng.find("Time", LookIn:=xlValues)
       If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
   Loop While Not c Is Nothing
```

so instead of c.entirerow.delete just change it to the line that colors the row

in the past I have used these 2 lines to color a row

```
iWarnColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
ws.rows(k).Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor
```

that makes the entire row yellow.

Comment: Are eh values for "CHANGE THIS TO WHAT YOU WANT TO FIND" comma separated like the following:  Set c = SrchRng.find("string1","string2", LookIn:=xlValues)

Comment: no what I have done if trying to find multiple values I just copy it again i can throw up what I have used in the past

Comment: did you test it?  the loop exits when c is nothing also if you set the AsrchRng to something like Set AsrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:E" & rows.Count)  it ends at the end of the range

Comment: Yeah I tested it in Excel 2002 and the whole thing hung up. Even if you used `FindNext` it would wrap around and find the first occurence again, so c will never be nothing unless there are no cells matching your criteria. The reason your delete example works is because it deletes a cell after it finds it, so eventually there are no more cells that match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I currently have in the macro.

```
Public Sub HighlightListedValues()
Dim strConcatList As String
Dim cell As Range

'Creates a string concatenating your list of strings, separated by |s
'e.g. "item1|item2|item3|item4|"
For Each cell In Sheets("32281r3|32342r1").Range("E1:E178")
    strConcatList = strConcatList & cell.Value & "|"
Next cell

'For each used cell in Column A of sheet1, check whether the value in that cell
'is contained within the concatenated string
For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("Gap Analysis").Range("E:E"), Sheets("Gap Analysis").UsedRange)
    If InStr(strConcatList, cell.Value) > 0 Then       'InStr returns 0 if the string isn't found
        cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Highlights the row in red if value found
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: I got the code working by subsituting Sheets("32281r3|32342r1") with Sheets("List") and creating a new sheet named List with all of my search items in column E1:E178.  Now this is working but the rows that match the search criteria are not being highlighted red.  Only the first 4 rows of the Gap Analysis sheet are.

Comment: One other thing to mention is that the cell contains other data other information.  For example, the cell could contain "The new line of cars have been released and a Ford has the code 32281r3".  Will If InStr(strConcatList, cell.Value) > 0 Then work?

Comment: Unfortunately that check won't work unless the code you're looking for is the only content of the cell.